# How to make a namespace visible inside a chrooted/NEWPID process

Tags: linux, chroot, namespace, network-namespaces

I create a new process using `CLONE_NEWPID` and `chroot` to `/mnt/`

Outside of that, I create a new netns using the `ip netns` command.

e.g.

```
ip netns add test1
```

Any idea how can I make the chrooted process, or its children, see this new netns?

Based on what I see on strace, I tried:

```
touch /mnt/var/run/netns/test1
ip netns exec test1 mount --bind /proc/self/ns/net /mnt/var/run/netns/test1
```

But didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Note that `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run` and should be "resolved" in advance or `/mnt/var/run` might point back to `/run` with the various commands.

At first glance this simpler command (rather than OP's which can never work as explained in the last note at the end) from initial namespace should be enough to allow `ip netns exec` to work from the chrooted *pid* namespace:

```
mount --bind /run/netns/test1 /mnt/run/netns/test1
```

but it isn't. It's not related to the *pid* namespace, but to *chroot*. Actually the whole problem is the same when not switching to a new *pid* namespace at all.

`ip netns exec` doesn't manipulate only *network* namespaces, but also has to manipulate *mount* namespaces and use *mount(2)* system calls for reasons I explained in this SF Q/A: [Cannot create nested network namespace](https://serverfault.com/questions/961504/cannot-create-nested-network-namespace/961592#961592).

---

### Problem: chroot

`/proc` should be mounted within the chroot for proper operations. With at least `/proc` mounted from within the chroot, using `strace` one can see `ip netns exec test1 ...` will enter a new *mount* namespace and fail to remount `/`:

```c
getuid()                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/netns/test1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
setns(3, CLONE_NEWNET)                  = 0
close(3)                                = 0
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)                    = 0
mount("", "/", 0x5595a749373f, MS_REC|MS_SLAVE, NULL) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "\"mount --make-rslave /\" failed: "..., 49) = 49
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

The remount fails with `EINVAL`: because of the *chroot*, `/` is not a mount point anymore.

Note that the *network* namespace part itself doesn't have a problem. So for example doing this from the chrooted side:

```
nsenter --net=/run/netns/test1 ip link
```

will succeed and display *test1*'s network interfaces, but will for example not switch relevant entries available in `/sys/` like would do `ip netns exec` (as described in my former link), should those be needed.

---

### Solution: add a bind mount over itself

The fix: bind-mount the *chroot* target to itself to forcibly turn it into a mount point, preferably in private mode to avoid interactions (especially when *systemd* turned `/` shared) before doing the *chroot*.

I reproduce below a working setup with shell commands.

I'm omitting some boiler plate, like probably mounting `/run` (aka init's `/mnt/run`) from a tmpfs etc. but mounting `/proc` from within the chroot should really be done.

first in term1:

```
~# unshare --fork --pid bash
~# echo $$
1
~# mount --bind --make-private /mnt /mnt
~# chroot /mnt bash
/# mount -t proc proc /proc
```

then in an unrelated term2:

```
 ~# ip netns add test1
 ~# mkdir -p /mnt/run/netns
 ~# touch /mnt/run/netns/test1
 ~# mount --bind /run/netns/test1 /mnt/run/netns/test1
```

again in term1:

```
/# ip netns exec test1 ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Notes:

- as stated before this issue has no relation to the *pid* namespace. Removing the command `unshare --fork --pid bash` will fix the same problem when using just a *chroot* without *pid* namespace.
- a mount command should *never* be run from within an `ip netns exec` command. Remember that `ip netns exec` itself creates a temporary mount namespace. Whatever mount is done within will disappear when `ip netns exec` ends. This is also explained in my previous link. Doing this instead would still fine:

  ```
  nsenter --net=/run/netns/test1 mount --bind /proc/self/ns/net /mnt/var/run/netns/test1
  ```

  but of course not needed since it's the exact same entity as can be verified  by having same inode in the *nsfs* virtual filesystem:

  ```
  ~# stat -f -c %T /run/netns/test1; stat -c %i /run/netns/test1
  nsfs
  4026533129
  ~# nsenter --net=/run/netns/test1 sh -c 'stat -f -L -c %T /proc/self/ns/net; stat -L -c %i /proc/self/ns/net'
  nsfs
  4026533129
  ```